# Multiplicative Harmonic Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, approximation, factorial, products

Is there any approximation formula for this equation? I have been trying to find approximations for it so I can create an approximation formula myself for something else, but for some reason I can't find any approximations online for this function although its simplicity. *I would also appreciate it if the approximation formula **didn't** include the factorial, gamma function, nor any recursive functions.*
$$f(x)=\prod_{n=1}^{x}\frac{x}{n}$$
Here some examples of the equations outputted.
$$(1/1) = 1$$
$$(2/2)*(2/1) = 2$$
$$(3/3)*(3/2)*(3/1) = 4.5$$
$$(4/4)*(4/3)*(4/2)*(4/1) = 10.66...$$
$$(5/5)*(5/4)*(5/3)*(5/2)*(5/1) = 26.0416...$$
$$(6/6)*(6/5)*(6/4)*(6/3)*(6/2)*(6/1) = 64.8$$

Comment: 6 should be 64.8. It is $x^x \over x!$; Sorry that is has a factorial, but you can use Sterlings approximation to approximate it.

Comment: @user619894 Sorry, you're correct! I guess I just can't avoid factorials on this one.

Comment: You can. Using Sterlings, I get $e^{x} \over {\sqrt(2\pi x)}$

Comment: @user619894 Oh thanks!